# undefined is not an object (evaluating '_reactNativeRouterFlux2.default.Router')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Here is my **containers/app.js** code

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
      render() {
        return (
          <Provider store={store}>
                <Router hideNavBar={true}>
                    <Schema
                      name="default"
                      sceneConfig={Navigator.SceneConfigs.FloatFromRight}
                    />
                    <Route
                      name="signIn"
                      component={SignIn}
                      initial={true}
                      wrapRouter={true}
                      title="SignIn"
                    />
                  </Router>
           </Provider>
        );
      }
    }
```

The error appearce on a render step, where is my problem?

Comment: what is our react router version?

Comment: "react-native-router-flux": "^4.0.0-beta.28",

Answer (score 0):

You missed a `r` in Router, also the tag is self closing, you don't need another  tag.

```
<Router
  name="signIn"
  component={SignIn}
  initial={true}
  wrapRouter={true}
  title="SignIn"
/>
```

Comment: if he used self closed tag then where . Route going to be defined?

Comment: import ReactNativeRouter, { Route, Schema } from 'react-native-router-flux';

Answer (score 0):

In your `package.json` add  following version.

```
"dependencies" : {
   //...other packages
   "react-native-router-flux": "4.0.0-beta.27",
   //...other packages
}
```

then do following step :

1. remove node_modules.
2. npm install

**You getting this issue because `^4.0.0-beta.28` version is broken.**

For more information **[`github#react-native-router-flux`](https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux/issues/2799)**